# PHP, как сгенерировать хэш пароля(*nix алгоритм) с символом "_" в SALT?

Tags: php, openssl, password-hash

В некотором legacy софте реализовано хэширование пользовательских паролей таким образом

```
# openssl passwd -salt $salt $password
```

Причем засада в том, что стандартный для всех `$salt` содержит символ "_" и никуда от него не деться.

Для автоматизации заведения пользователей пишу небольшую локальную админку на php и столкнулся с тем, что стандартная функция `crypt` считает символ "_" запрещенным для использования SALT.

Есть какие нибудь мысли, как реализовать это хеширование средствами PHP, без использования `exec/system`?

Для теста:

```
host:/ # openssl passwd -salt U_ 12345
U_n4Re0OhGFLU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению никак.

Проблема в использовании недопустимого символа в `SALT` для используемого алгоритма, что ведет к неопределенному поведению: где-то(PHP5) `crypt()` генерирует некорректный хэш, где-то(PHP7) ругается на некорректный символ, где-то просто возвращает лютую дичь, вроде `*0`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам подойдет библиотека php_openssl.
Она предоставляет интерфейсы к openssl такие как:

```
string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )
```

и

```
string openssl_decrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )
```

Они помогут соблюсти обратную совместимость. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-encrypt.php).

Для получения hash-а можно использовать:

```
string openssl_digest ( string $data , string $method [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

Метод указать "RSA-SHA256". Полный список методов доступен через openssl_get_md_methods().

Comment: openssl_encrypt шифрует данные по ключу. Мне же надо получить хэш   пароля по стандартному unix алгоритму, как его делает 'openssl passwd'

Comment: А какой стандартный алгоритм в вашей системе? Если это SHA256 и нужен только hash то можно использовать openssl_digest.

    string openssl_digest ( string $data , string $method [, bool $raw_output = false ] )

Метод указать "RSA-SHA256". Полный список методов доступен через openssl_get_md_methods().

Comment: DES с двухсимвольной salt. Пока из всей библиотеки openssl_ ничего подходящего не нашел